# Linux AVR-IDE development, vim integration

Tags: linux, qt, vim, integration, avr

I'm starting to develop an AVR-IDE for developing various AVR-Boards on Linux.
I just want a simple IDE with tools for debugging(simavr), compiling(gcc for avr), and uploading (avrdude). Maybe at a later moment I will be adding tools for setting breakpoints, setting fuses's and so on.
I'm totally open to any programming IDE / programming language with whom I would like to realize it. Only requirement is a simple integration of a "VIM like editor" (preferably with syntax highlighting and plugin support, but I could add that later on). Even an emulation of the standard functions of VIM would be enough. But writing the complete VIM emulator by myself would be too much work I think (there is probably a better workaround).
Do you know any way of integrating VIM into a self made qt application, or a gtk+ application, or a gtk# application... ?
Tips on chosing which language I shall use, and tips on how to integrate a simpe VIM editor are welcome! (but don't think I don't have experience with the different programming languages / IDE's, gtk+, gtk#, qt...) I just want to hear your considerations.

Thanks alot,
ICEBERG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use what *QtCreator* (already mentioned in @[Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652/kuba-ober)'s answer) uses: [FakeVim](https://github.com/hluk/FakeVim).

If the level of emulation doesn't satisfy you, and you're up for more work, try **Neovim** - which is actually based on Vim. You can study [neovim-qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt) in order to see how to integrate it to your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you care for writing code, and can wrap your head around large code bases, then Qt Creator would be a very good choice. You can start with the bare metal support that's already there, and develop plugins for the debugger, etc.